# iOS freezing and threading with detachNewThreadSelector

Tags: ios, multithreading, thread-safety

I am working on an application that was designed by someone else.  The application is full of calls like this:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadPhotoImage) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

and

```
DownloadPhotoThread *thread = [[DownloadPhotoThread alloc] initWithFriendArray:_friendsList delegate:self];
[self.arrDownloadThreads addObject:thread];
[thread start];
```

And randomly I will get into situations where the entire ui locks, and the phone/simulator no longer respond to touches.  Just to be clear, the device never unfreezes.  If I hit pause during a debug session, I see a thread is sitting on a start or detachNewThreadSelector line.

Today I was able to narrow down a cause when these locks happen.  I just added the Zendesk form controller (found here: https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_ios_sdk/blob/master/DropboxSampleApp/FormViewController.m)

Which has this code:

```
- (void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row > 1) {
        CGSize s = [description sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(description.frame.size.width, 10000)];
        float dh = MAX(s.height, 115);
        description.frame = CGRectMake(description.frame.origin.x, 
                                   description.frame.origin.y, 
                                   description.frame.size.width, 
                                   dh);
        return dh;
    }
    return 44.0;
}
```

I can easily reproduce the lockup condition by typing a character and return over and over into this text box. (this resizes the height of the table view)

In some cases I am able to prevent the lockup condition by wrapping the offender with a dispatch_async() block like this:

```
DownloadPhotoThread *thread = [[DownloadPhotoThread alloc] initWithFriendArray:_friendsList delegate:self];
[self.arrDownloadThreads addObject:thread];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [thread start];
});
```

But in other cases I can't because the offending code is in a complex library such as ASIHTTPRequest or XMPPFramework.  Do you have any advice on what exactly is happening here?

Another thing.  When I hit pause in this condition, this is what the main thread says:

```
Thread 1
com.apple.main-thread
0 objc_msgSend
....
25 UIApplicationMain
26 main
```

pausing and unpausing will always find main at some assembly instruction inside objc_msgSend.

Thanks for your help cuz I'm seriously stumped here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the crash was caused by a bug in https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_ios_sdk/  . I've made a pull request and submitted to them for review.